# is there a way to count how many firestore onSnapshot are active in my app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building some logic in my app that dynamically discards query [onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#onsnapshot_5) listeners and creates new ones. I want to test that resources are been set free by the correct use of the [unsubscribe](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.unsubscribe.md#unsubscribe_interface) function.

I don't have access to the unsubscribe reference to spy on it. I was wondering if there is a way to know how many active onSnapshot listeners are active, so I could expect the correct count on them.

I'm using the version 9 of the firebase web javascript sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built into the Firebase SDKs for counting the active Firestore listeners. If you need something like that, you'll have to build it yourself by increasing a counter when you attach a listener, and decreasing it when you remove a listener.